# How to find base tables referenced by views in SQL Standard Implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find all the tables that are referenced by a specific view.

Since it is not MySQL, I cannot do `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.

When I try to do something like `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE`, I get the following error:

> The SQL contains the following terms which are not allowed: view_table_usage.

Anyone know how I can bypass this problem?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? sql` is very generic

Comment: Are you only doing a simple select on that table or are you actually trying to modify it in someway (insert/update/delete)? Your partial error message is suspicious.

Comment: The RDBMS is MS-SQL. I am just trying to do a simple select on the table.

Comment: Could you post the entire error message along with the query you are trying to execute?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE` is the code that I used. The error I get is **The SQL contains the following terms which are not allowed: view_table_usage**. Also please keep in mind that the this is SQL used through a specific web application.

Comment: I suspect this error is *not* coming from your DBMS, but rather your application software/library. What are you using? How are you calling this?

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I am using version 10.50.2500.0

Comment: @Nicarus I am using an online application called CATSWeb.

Comment: My guess is that the application is preventing you from viewing that - that is not a standard error message.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will contact one of the application devs. I just wanted to make sure that my input command was valid.